# Thermal resistance in vacuum

Tags: mosfet, thermal, radiation, space

Is it possible to obtain an approximate guess of what the thermal resistance of a device (i.e. a power MOSFET) would be in a vacuum based on the ambient thermal resistance value provided in the datasheet? Obviously it would be higher, as the only way to carry away heat is through radiation, but how much? What would be a reasonable safety factor to use when estimating temperature rise of a power circuit in a vacuum environment?

Comment: Most of the power will be lost by conduction to the PCB and (if you design it taht way) to the case metalwork. These give much larger areas for radiation : choose their emissivity wisely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's a way: multiply the [Emissivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emissivity) of the package with its surface with the emission of a black body.

(The latter is about 450 W/(m²), at 300 K; emissivity is a factor between 0 and 1; I'm sure your semiconductor manufacturer has a datasheet or application note that says something about its plastics' emissivity)

> What would be a reasonable safety factor to use when estimating temperature rise of a power circuit in a vacuum environment?

Do you need that? There's usually both a "junction-package resistance" which is exactly that: the resistance for heat from the junction to the surface of your device. You'd add the resistivity of the radiation to that, done.

Comment: Also: don't forget that for out-gassing might be a relevant factor for vacuum chamber application, and space-hardness requires more than sufficient cooling (especially large semiconductors are fantastic ionizing-radiation detectors... whether you want that or not).

Comment: I've been looking for information on the emissivity of TO-92 plastic, but so far I'm drawing blanks. My best guess is that it's relatively high, i.e. around .9. Do you have any sources that could help me get a better estimate for what it should be?

Answer (score 2):

The power lost by radiation is given by the [Stefan Boltzman law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law).

It tells the power radiated per surface area due to Black-body radiation.

I.e.

- all you need to know is the surface area of the component and this law and
- you can't just use a "safety factor" because the mechanism of getting rid of heat is quite different (with atmosphere in most cases the biggest part is by convection which is not present at all in vacuum).

Answer (score 0):

Be aware the thermal resistance of standard thickness PCB foil is 70 ° C per watt per square of foil, for any size square.

So don't ignore the friendliness of the PCB for extracting heat and spreading it to metal mounting standoffs and then to the system chassis.

Consider how much heat can move thru the THREE thick metal leads (GATE, Source, Drain) of the FET. Then have wide foil to remove the heat, and transfer thru the FR-4 onto underlying copper planes.

A high current FET likely has the metal leads directly bonded to the Silicon, without BondWires between the lead and the silicon.

ASK the Manufacturer Application Engineer, or the Packaging Engineer. They will know.